# HTML: Autofill form in bootstrap modal

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

In most HTML forms when I start typing something (say birth date) navigators propose to sit with previous similar entries. For instance on [html form submit](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit) the second visit offers me the first visit entries.

However, when using a bootstrap modal containing a form, the same does not happen, for instance: [with a form inside](http://mode87.com/untame/demo/modalcontact/).

I do not want to use jquery autocomplete since I do not have a list of potential answers, I just want to have the same behavior in and outside modals.

Thanks.

Comment: max namara How did you solve this, Actually I am facing same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Browser autofills are notoriously unpredictable - they make educated guesses about the data based on the `name` attribute of inputs. It's unlikely you'll be able to get this behavior consistently cross-browser.

Comment: You are right. However I am satisfied enough by the autofill on classical forms but for modal forms I cannot get anything close to an autofill, except for the chrome complete autofill for addresses which is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this :

add the attribute **autocomplete = "on"** on your form, 
maybe it will do the job.

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" autocomplete="on">
    First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I tried the attribute both on the form and on all fields and it makes no difference.

Comment: by the way on your link when i double click (or start typing) on name and email input i have an autocomplete choice that appear  : http://mode87.com/untame/demo/modalcontact/

Answer (score 0):

Read through [this article](https://cloudfour.com/thinks/autofill-what-web-devs-should-know-but-dont/) it should help get things working for you.

Example:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" autocomplete="name">
<input type="tel" id="tel" name="tel" autocomplete="home tel">
```